# FileNotFoundException when loading textfile into android project

Tags: java, android, hashmap, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception

I've been working on an Android Bid Page App for a class and I can't seem to find out why my program throws a FileNotFoundException when my path is correct (relative path). I'm using this class to read in a file that contains string values of Item objects and create items to put into my temporary HashMap and return it. Thanks in advance!!

```
    public class FileLoader 
    {
        private File path = new File("items");
        private static File textFile;

        //fileName is called with "AllItems.txt"
        public FileLoader(String fileName)
        {
            textFile = new File(path, fileName);
        }

        public Map<Integer, Item> getItems()
        {
            //Item is a custom Object
            Map<Integer, Item> items = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
            int i = 1;
            try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));)
            {
                String itemToParse;
                while((itemToParse = bf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //ItemParser is a custom static class to create an item from one string
                items.put(i, ItemParser.ParseItem(itemToParse));
                i++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`  or `Context.getDatabasePath()` or  `Context.getFilesDir()` etc methods to get/obtain the relative file path.

Comment: What you have in your parent path in File constructor?

Comment: I am not familiar with Environment. I understand that using `System.getenv()` returns a `Map<String,String>` of the environment, If this is the correct way of using it how would you set the environment?

Comment: UPDATE** I had looked up Java Environment instead of android Environment. If i had to guess `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` grabs the relative path from the absolute path but would this persist past my own computer?